# ANTLR4 pushMode, popMode, mode

Tags: antlr4

I have a grammar that fails when I use 'pushMode' and 'popMode' but works when I use 'mode'.

This grammar construct that works:

```
TAG: '{'                                -> pushMode( TAG_MODE ), skip;
TEXT: ~[{]+;

mode TAG_MODE;
     TAG_COMMENT: '*'                   -> skip, mode( COMMENT_MODE );

mode COMMENT_MODE;
     END_COMMENT:  .*? '*}'             -> skip, popMode;
     COMMENT_TEXT: .                    -> type( SYNTAX_ERROR ), popMode;
```

Now if I change the TAG_COMMENT to use 'pushMode' and 'popMode' instead it fails an I loose everything from the comment tag onwards.

This grammar construct that fails:

```
TAG: '{'                                -> pushMode( TAG_MODE ), skip;
TEXT: ~[{]+;

mode TAG_MODE;
     TAG_COMMENT: '*'                   -> skip, pushMode( COMMENT_MODE ), popMode;

mode COMMENT_MODE;
     END_COMMENT:  .*? '*}'             -> skip, popMode;
     COMMENT_TEXT: .                    -> type( SYNTAX_ERROR ), popMode;
```

Can anybody explain the difference to me; in my mind they should be functionally equivalent except that it second method uses one more level of lexer stack.

I would actually prefer to use the failing construct as it's too easy to get the lexer stack screwed up using 'mode'(goto) whereas if everything uses 'pushMode' and 'popMode' it's much easier to keep the lexer stack in order.

Also is it ok to use an empty set to exit a mode?
Something like:

```
mode MODE1;
     TAG_IDENT:  IDENT;
     TAG_EMPTY:           -> popMode; // Hopefully exits and doesn't consume a token
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

In the `TAG_COMMENT` rule you use `pushMode` immediately followed by `popMode`. The result is the same as though both instructions were removed. The reverse order would have had a very different effect, as shown in item 1 below.

1. You could reverse the order of the `pushMode` and `popMode` instructions in `TAG_COMMENT`, but that would be semantically equivalent to a simpler single `mode` command:

   ```
   TAG_COMMENT
     : '*'
       -> skip, mode(COMMENT_MODE)
     ;
   ```
2. Remove the `popMode` action from the `COMMENT_TEXT` rule (if the comment is unterminated, the entire rest of the input is inside the comment).

Comment: I don't quite understand. If I remove the 'popMode' from TAG_COMMENT how does it ever get back to DEFAULT_MODE mode? The way I understand the calling sequence would be. DEFAULT_MODE->TAG_MODE->COMMENT_MODE->TAG_MODE leaving it in TAG_MODE and never returning back to DEFAULT_MODE.

Comment: @Terry151151 Thank you for the explanation. I now realize that the `popMode` instruction in `TAG_COMMENT` was intended to affect the `TAG_MODE` mode, but by pushing `COMMENT_MODE` *before* the `popMode` instruction it was actually affecting the `COMMENT_MODE` mode. I have updated my answer to show the correction in step 1.

Comment: Actually I would have thought that the order wouldn't have mattered. Ie: 'pushMode', 'popMode', 'popMode' or 'popMode', 'pushMode', 'popMode' or 'mode', 'popMode' all would have been functionally equivalent. I's OK to use mode in a small example but when you have lots of modes and there all using 'mode' the code becomes very spaghetti like and it becomes very easy to get the lexer stack wrong, whereas the 'pushMode' 'popMode' sequence (subroutine style) is almost fool proof.

Comment: As a note I've tested using 'popMode' first followed by 'pushMode' and it works fine. Can you please explain why using it the other way round doesn't ie: 'pushMode' followed by 'popMode'.

Comment: I think I just realised where there error in my thinking is; 'pushMode' doesn't act like a subroutine call and halt processing at this point until the 'popMode' from the called mode is executed. All it does is move a lexical stack pointer and then moves on to the next instruction. So when you have 'pushMode' followed by 'popMode' the 'popMode' immediately undoes the previous 'pushMode'. Which means I stuck with spaghetti code.

Comment: @Terry151151 That interpretation of the commands is correct. `pushMode` and `popMode` simply perform a single stack operation and then move on to the next command in the list.

Answer (score 0):

@Terry151151 I am new to Antlr, but I was able to achieve a similar result by adding a second 'popMode' in the secondary mode.  This would probably just work for modes with one rule where it's pushing and needs to pop when the secondary mode is done.

Try changing the following lines:

```
 TAG_COMMENT: '*'                   -> skip, pushMode( COMMENT_MODE );
```

and

```
 END_COMMENT:  .*? '*}'             -> skip, popMode, popMode;
```